# PyGTK: How do I make an image automatically scale to fit its parent widget?

Tags: python, image, gtk, pygtk

I have a PyGTK app that needs to load an image of unknown size, however I am having the problem that if the image is either very big or very small, the window layout becomes distorted and hard to use. I need some way of making the image automatically scale to fit its parent widget. Unfortunately, after doing some research, it seems there is no code, built in or otherwise, that does what I'm looking for.

How could I go about writing something to do this? I would have thought that somebody would have written some code for this already; is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use widget.get_allocation() to find out the size of the parent widget and pixbuf.scale_simple to scale the image, like this:

```
allocation = parent_widget.get_allocation()
desired_width = allocation.width
desired_height = allocation.height

pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file('your_image.png')
pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(desired_width, desired_height, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
image = gtk.image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

If you want the image to scale each time the window is resized, you'll have to put the code above (or something similar, to avoid loading the image from disk every time) in a function connected to the size_allocate signal of the parent widget. To avoid infinite loops, make sure that the image you put in the widget doesn't alter its size again.

References:

- [How to resize an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269320/scale-an-image-in-gtk) (I think you already visited that)
- [About the "resize" event](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2000-October/msg00210.html)
- [Other link about resizing, in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060039/gtk-detecting-window-resize-from-the-user)

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks. I used `image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)` rather than `image = gtk.image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)` however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an except that accomplishes this task on a drawing area:

```
    self.spash_pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file('myfile.png')
    ...

    def on_draw(self, widget, cairo_ct):
        """
            draw
        """
        self._cairo_ct = cairo_ct
        self._width = widget.get_allocated_width()
        self._height = widget.get_allocated_height()

        self._draw_cover(self.spash_pixbuf)

    def _draw_cover(self, pixbuf):
        """
            Paint pixbuf to cover drawingarea.
        """
        img_width = float(pixbuf.get_width())
        img_height = float(pixbuf.get_height())
        # Scale
        width_ratio = self._width / img_width
        height_ratio = self._height / img_height
        scale_xy = max(height_ratio, width_ratio)
        # Center
        off_x = (self._width  - round(img_width*scale_xy)) //2
        off_y = (self._height - round(img_height*scale_xy)) //2

        # Paint
        self._cairo_ct.save()

        self._cairo_ct.translate(off_x, off_y)
        self._cairo_ct.scale(scale_xy, scale_xy)

        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(self._cairo_ct, pixbuf, 0, 0)
        self._cairo_ct.paint()

        self._cairo_ct.restore()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some small snippet class which allows you to use auto scaled image.

```
import gtk


class ImageEx(gtk.Image):
    pixbuf = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageEx, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.connect("size-allocate", self.on_size_allocate)

    def set_pixbuf(self, pixbuf):
        """
        use this function instead set_from_pixbuf
        it sets additional pixbuf, which allows to implement autoscaling
        """
        self.pixbuf = pixbuf
        self.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)

    def on_size_allocate(self, obj, rect):
        # skip if no pixbuf set
        if self.pixbuf is None:
            return

        # calculate proportions for image widget and for image
        k_pixbuf = float(self.pixbuf.props.height) / self.pixbuf.props.width
        k_rect = float(rect.height) / rect.width

        # recalculate new height and width
        if k_pixbuf < k_rect:
            newWidth = rect.width
            newHeight = int(newWidth * k_pixbuf)
        else:
            newHeight = rect.height
            newWidth = int(newHeight / k_pixbuf)

        # get internal image pixbuf and check that it not yet have new sizes
        # that's allow us to avoid endless size_allocate cycle
        base_pixbuf = self.get_pixbuf()
        if base_pixbuf.props.height == newHeight and base_pixbuf.props.width == newWidth:
            return

        # scale image
        base_pixbuf = self.pixbuf.scale_simple(
            newWidth,
            newHeight,
            gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR
        )

        # set internal image pixbuf to scaled image
        self.set_from_pixbuf(base_pixbuf)
```

And small usage example:

```
class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

        # create new ImageEx
        self.image = ImageEx()
        # set size request, to limit image size
        self.image.set_size_request(width=400, height=400)
        # load image from file, change path with path of some of your image
        pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("path/to/your/image.jpeg")

        # that's the key moment, instead `set_from_pixbuf` function
        # we use our newly created set_pixbuf, which do some additional assignments
        self.image.set_pixbuf(pixbuf)

        # add widget and show window
        self.window.add(self.image)
        self.window.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow()
    gtk.main()
```